Is the notion of compactness of operators preserved under quasi-similarity?
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T \in \mathcal L (H).$ Then $T$ is said to be quasi-invertible if it is one-one and has dense range. The operator $T$ is said to be quasi-similar to an operator $S \in \mathcal L (H)$ if there exist quasi-invertible operators $X$ and $Y$ such that $TX = XS$ and $YT = SY.$

Question $:$ Let $S$ and $T$ be quasi-similar operators with $S$ compact. Can we say that $T$ is compact as well? If not, then is there any notion of compactness under quasi-similar transformations?

Any suggestion in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Let $H_0$ be infinite-dimensional and separable, and fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$. Let $E_k$ be the orthogonal projection onto the $e_k$. Let
$$
K=\sum_n\frac1n\,E_n. 
$$
Then $K$ is compact. It is injective with dense range, so it is quasi-invertible. Let $H=H_0\oplus H_0$, and
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}0&K\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad T=\begin{bmatrix}0&I\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\qquad
X=\begin{bmatrix} I&0\\0&K\end{bmatrix},\qquad
Y=\begin{bmatrix} K&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix} . 
$$
Then $X,Y$ are quasi-invertible, and
$$
TX=\begin{bmatrix} 0&K\\0&0\end{bmatrix} = XS, 
$$
and
$$
YT=\begin{bmatrix} 0&K\\0&0\end{bmatrix} =SY. 
$$
Then $S$ and $T$ and quasi-similar, $S$ is compact, and $T$ is not compact.
